# Code working a bit differently between Powershell.exe and Powershell ISE - Sort-Object behavior

Tags: powershell, sort-object

I've got a bit of code to get hyperlinks from http webpage - find all items matching criteria, then find newest by sorting them and use it's InnerText as source for download. All hyperlinks get assigned a 7-digit number at the end of their name with greater number for newer files.

Code:

```
$Web = ((Invoke-WebRequest "http://serveraddress/Export/").Links | 
         Where-Object {$_.href -like “xx_yyyyyy_auto_standard*”} | 
           Sort Name –Desc | Select –Last 1).innertext
Start-BitsTransfer -Source http://serveraddress/Export/$Web -Destination C:\autoreports\
```

Now, when I run above in Powershell.exe (e.g. when launching .ps1 file by right-click and "Run with Powershell") I get the oldest file downloaded. When I run above in Powershell ISE I get newest file. When I changed -Last to -First in Powershell.exe code works as expected.

I can easily change this, but since I'm very new to Powershell - why is there such difference between Powershell ISE and "standard"? Thanks in advance! While this might be rookie question, I did not find - or understand - reason for the difference.

Comment: @lit: You're right - I've edited the question to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement [Jordan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319311/45375), which solves your specific problem:

As stated, **`Sort-Object` *quietly accepts nonexistent properties* to sort by**.

Unfortunately, **as of Windows PowerShell v5.1, attempting to sort by a nonexistent property *results in seemingly random output order***:

```
WinPS> 1, 2, 3, 4 | Sort-Object -Property Foo
3
4
1
2
```

Fortunately, this problem has been fixed in PowerShell *Core*, where the input order is preserved in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The link objects don't have a property of "Name" so sorting by Name won't work.

Comment: Shouldn't the code not work at all then? Because it definitely does in my case - file is downloaded, simply there's different behaviour PS ISE vs. PS

Comment: The Sort-object cmdlet will not throw errors if the property doesn't exist. It will simply pass the objects through. Sort by blahblahblah if you want to test. This is why the first behavior is inconsistent. I doubt this is related to the ISE.